# How to wrap an image around a path using Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am trying to make model of some chemical reactions. I am using a circle path. The only thing I know how to do is wrap text around the path but not sure how to wrap an image. The image is a thick arrow with some formula written on it (all rasterized).

To give you a better idea, it looks kind of like [this](https://www.123rf.com/photo_38999069_stock-vector-circular-arrows-diagram.html) except there will be things written on the arrows and I need to have space between them where I write the results of the reactions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to use Illustrator, altough the next is equally available in Photoshop, too. It's warping to arc.

[image]

You can bend any image to arc. The bending percentage = How many percents of 180 degrees. In Illustrator it is in Object > Envelope Distort > Make with Warp. In Photoshop it's in Edit > Transform > Warp, mode option=Arc

To get usable results the original must be horizontal. After warping you must rotate the result to the wanted position.

Text remains editable after warping.

In illustator you can also make a brush. Only drag a shape to the brushes collection and define it to be a Pattern Brush. The shape can be bended along arbitary curve. (see NOTE1)

The curve to which a pattern brush is applied, must not have tight bends, because they distort texts unreadable.

An example of using pattern brush:

[image]

NOTE1: Legacy illustrator do not accept arbitary shapes to be used as brushes. The shape must be a path or a group of paths. Outlined text is OK, but it cannot be edited.